# How to work with mouse events (MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseMove,..) in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn from a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I'm trying to get and handle the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events within a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyHeader" Binding="{Binding Path=MyPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
Visibility="{Binding Data.VisibilityPath, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" />
```

However if I use `Mouse.MouseEnter = MyEventHandler` I get the following error message:

> Suppression State Error       'MyEventHandler' is not valid. 'MouseEnter'
>   is not an event on 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCheckBoxColumn'.

Is the only way to go around this to create my own `DataGridTemplateColumn` containing checkboxes and using the events on the checkboxes directly? This would be unfortunate, since I have to do this on older code and don't want to rewrite all the datagrids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Tree of DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJrh.png)

In the visual tree of `DataGrid`,there aren't any control which type is `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`,you should binding the EventSetter to `CheckBox` or `DataGridCell`

Edit:Update

```xml
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style>
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.MouseEnter" Handler="CheckBox_MouseEnter"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: OK, but this implies that I would have to create my own custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a Checkbox in it as described in the OP. I really want to avoid this, if possible.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I never use `DataGridTemplateColumn`.If you used `DataGridComboBoxColumn`,the wpf interpreter while create the control like the picture,you can try it and see what the visual tree is.

Comment: @RolandDeschain If you mean you have to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` to binding the event,see how to use `EventSetter` in the `DataGrid.Resources.Style`

Comment: It seems something was not quite clear: I mean the current code uses `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. Using those, I can't access the `checkbox` item (at least I wouldn't know how) - therefore I can't use the eventsetter directly on the checkboxes. To do this, I would habe to change the `DataGridCheckBoxColumns` to `DataGridTemplateColumn` with checkbox as template - however this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @RolandDeschain I got it.Try to add the `EventSetter` in `DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle`,it will be helpful,I will update the code to this answer,check it.

Comment: That did the trick, thx a lot. I didn't know you can access events of children (checkbox) in this way. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `EventSetter`

```
<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="CheckBox_MouseEnter"/>
```

Comment: I have already tried that, it results in the same error message unfortunately. (Tried to create a style for the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle` element with your described eventsetter